# Is it possible to parse fdf content by using the PDFLib library?

Tags: c++, pdf, markup, pdflib, fdf

Does PDFLib provide API for parsing an FDF file?
Or for exporting markups to PDF, directly by giving the FDF content as an input?

Thanks in advance!
Dean